# Firestore application crash when retrieving data

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When I want to load specific field into ArrayMap onCreate of the activity the app crash and when i want to see log the field exist but after retrieving the data, my app crashes.

Here is the pseudo code:

```
private void loadData() {
        mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("Jobs").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
        CollectionReference jobList = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Jobs");
        jobList.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful())
                {
                    List<String> listJobss = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (DocumentSnapshot doc: task.getResult())
                    {

//                        Log.d("lissss",doc.getString("jobName"));
                        Log.d("Itwork",doc.getData().toString());
//Crash
//                        listJobss.add(doc.get("jobName").toString());

                    }
                    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplication(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listJobss);
                    list.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: What's the crash? Could you share the log messages?

Comment: for example when i want to retrieve an attribute:                         listJobss.add(doc.get("jobName").toString());
the error: java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference

Comment: did you check the permission of the the database?

Comment: // Make sure to write security rules for your app before that time, or else
    // your app will lose access to your Firestore database
    match /{document=**} {
      // allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(2020, 1, 11);
            allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}

Comment: I think you need a where clause instead:
jobList.whereEqualTo("jobName", true).get().addOnCompleteListener ( ... ). Have a look at this one: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection

Comment: It's not the case

Comment: At which line of code does that error occur? Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: here listJobss.add(doc.get("jobName").toString());

Comment: @MondherEssid If your app crashes, there is an error message and stack trace in the logcat output of your app. Please copy/paste both into you question, by clicking the edit link under it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you check if task result exists and if it's not null.
While your task may be successfull and docs may exist in the collection you're looking for, their data might be null (as you can have docs with no data inside), that may be crashing your app.

```
if(task.isSuccessful())

{

    if (task.getResult().exists() && task.getResult() != null) {
        List<String> listJobss = new ArrayList<>();
        for (DocumentSnapshot doc : task.getResult()) {

//                        Log.d("lissss",doc.getString("jobName"));
            Log.d("Itwork", doc.getData().toString());
//Crash
//                        listJobss.add(doc.get("jobName").toString());

        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplication(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listJobss);
        list.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the problem when i see the log  the result is showing on the log and then crash so the data exist

Comment: Already shown 
java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference

Comment: Did you try using `doc.getString("jobName").toString()`

Comment: I did same problem

Answer (score 0):

I solved this By  retrieving the whole object then i retrieve the desired field

JobsData data = doc.toObject(JobsData.class);
  listJobss.add(data.getJobName());